# Is there any tool can fetch all the http responses automatically?

Tags: google-chrome, fiddler, browser-automation

The website has more than 20 pages. I need to verify the responses of each page to confirm if the response resources(js, css, images, htmls) has a certain parameter appended. For example: http://localhost/service/test.png**?ver=12010345**
,where ver=12010345 is the keyword I am going to check.

Now how I achieve it is open the developer tool in chrome, refresh each page and copy all the records in Network panel in a text file, and then use perl to check it line by line. For 20 pages I need to repeat this action 20 times. Obviously this solution is not that automatic, that's why I am asking if there is any tool can automate this process.

Answer (score 0):

You can preserve log in Network panel, navigate to these 20 pages and then use perl or any text editor to search through the records.